# Creating a tag so that our developers can track the related questions

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags

We need to create [crossrider](/questions/tagged/crossrider), and track it so that our developers can find and answer the questions and bug reports on such.

We are writing a script that will send us an SMS every time a question is posted with that tag by reading the tag XML feed.

The only issue is that a tag can only be created by a Stack Overflow user with a reputation of 1500 and above.

May anyone please create the [crossrider](/questions/tagged/crossrider) tag for us?

Comment: Stack Overflow is not your personal bug tracker

Comment: It's incredible how often "I love SO so much" and "I ignored your rules because it suited me" appear in the same post

Comment: Get rep > 1500 and do it. With a popular product and expert know how of it, it shouldn't be that difficult.

Comment: @MichaelMrozek I can already foresee the amount of edits that will need to be made because some people weren't aware of the no signature rule. One post and it violates 2 obvious rules... This **is** going to be interesting.

Comment: Was not aware of the no signature rule - was about to remove it, but some one was quicker then me :)

Comment: I work for a company who's looking to use a few sites on the Stack Exchange network as additional avenues of support for our customers, and this is certainly a lesson for me how not to go about doing it. No offense to the team at Crossrider, but the consensus from responders has been eye-opening.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Users can't just "create" a tag -- it has to be attached to a post. In theory you should wait until someone asks a crossrider question and thinks to include the tag, or you should find an existing question that needs the tag and ask someone to add it to that question specifically. However, it looks like [Oded](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1583/oded) already found [an existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6751153/how-to-redirect-to-a-bookmark-url-in-crossrider) and added the [crossrider](/questions/tagged/crossrider) tag to it a few minutes ago, so the [feed](https://stackoverflow.com/feeds/tag?tagnames=crossrider&sort=newest) should be working now

As for your general question, it's fine for users to ask crossrider questions here, as long as they make sense on Stack Overflow. Things like:

> we think its platform can provide the BEST way for us to communicate with our developers, and for our developers to communicate with each other.

don't sound like good uses of SO at all -- people shouldn't be posting crossrider bugs here, and your developers certainly shouldn't be tracking issues through questions and answers

Comment: Yeah! Take 'em to school Mike!

Comment: Thanks Michael for your answer. 
Obviously Stackoverflow platform will not be used as bug tracker(!), but for more for development questions, such as: "How can I do cross domain requests", "How to include remote js files etc..", "How can I access the local database" etc..

Thanks @Oded for adding the tag for us. I really appreciate it!

Comment: "Users can't just "create" a tag -- it has to be added to an existing post." is in disagreement with http://stackoverflow.com/privileges/create-tags

Comment: @AakashM It's not a disagreement - it's just how the system works. The privilege tells you that you can add a tag that doesn't already exist to a question, thus "creating" the tag. There is no other way (UI, etc.) to create tags.

Comment: @AakashM See the "How do I create a new tag?" section: "Simply enter a new tag with your question and it will be created"

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear at all. The privilege says "Simply enter a new tag with your question" which suggests that a new tag can be created *with* (ie at the same time as) a *new* question; whereas this answer suggests tag creation can only happen as part of a question *edit*.

Comment: @AakashM Oh, quite right. Edited to clarify

Comment: @ShmueliAhdut Just for the record. The down votes on your question indicates how much the community disagrees with your plan to do this, apart from having the tag created. I would honestly suggest you reconsider the whole concept. Your team is extremely welcome to answer questions about the product here, but keep in mind it may not work the way you want it too, so rather keep it informal and not a process.

Comment: @Diago, I understand why people feel its not OK to ask to add a tag unnaturally - but at the end of the day developers will benefit from this!

Comment: @ShmueliAhdut Your missing the point. My statement is not about the tag, my statement is about your whole idea of using SO as a support forum. The community as a whole does not consider it a good idea. Also, considering you had to ask for the tag to be created, it doesn't seem like a lot of the 60K+ developers on SO actually uses your product.