# Linking answers to their related questions edit history?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, revisions-list

Would it not be beneficial to be able to see (specifically) what the history entry (assuming the question is edited) of a question an answer relates to?

It happened to me recently, that guy asking a question edited his answer after receiving some first feedback and answers under the question were, after a while answering, essentially two different questions. One of them is not visible anymore. The history of a question may be looked up (I do not see it, but Meta search says otherwise?), but there is no way to know what exactly the answering guy was answering.

The point of Stack Overflow is to get answers, and fast, but it, in my opinion, should try to make it not confusing for future readers. If at least they try to pull the effort and understand the process happening after question was asked (question/answer time helps, but is difficult to work with). And I believe this is a feature that might help in a case as I described.

Comment: Having an option to mark an edit as "changed focus" would be helpful. If selected then all previous answers should display a link to the old edit.

Answer (score 2):

The [timeline view](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14643/full-timeline-of-a-question) can help with this, but it's still under development and isn't linked anywhere yet. For example, the timeline for [Creating a tag so that our developers can track the related questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/110532/creating-a-tag-so-that-our-developers-can-track-the-related-questions) is here: https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/110532/timeline

The oldest event is at the bottom, so if you read it from the bottom up you can see the original question text, my answer, random's question edit, the OP's question edit, and then my answer edit. Since it has the option to show the entire body of a given post, you can easily see what the question looked like when each answer was posted